# Colour scale based on how far value is from other cell value

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I have a column of targets (`C2:C30`) and a column of projections (`D2:D30`).

I've been able to conditionally format the projections to highlight values either above or below target, but I want to expand this into a colour scale to be able to identify more quickly how *far* from the target my projection is.

For example, if `D:D` is above 90% of `C:C`, a green colouring would suffice. 80-90% would be amber, below 80% would be red. In an ideal world, a fully fledged colour scale would be great but at this moment in time I'll be happy with anything more sophisticated than my current above/below setup.

I believe I could use a series of stacked conditional formats but thought there might be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Are you comparing cells in the same row? Or if the whole of column D is above 90% of C, ... What does your data look like?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. Yes to comparing cells in the same row, so each row treated as an individual target/projection. So row 2: Unique users, 3: Pageviews, 4: Pages per session, etc etc.

Comment: `Conditional Formatting > Format all cells based on their values > Format Style: 2-Color Scale`. This will be gradient based on inputted values. Otherwise, you can play with `Format Style` options.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own scale,

Create first rule using something like:

```
=C2*1.9<D2
```

Apply this in Cell D2, then apply to D2:D30,

Then create second rule:

```
=C2*1.8<D2
```

And so on..